# Show that maximal abelian normal subgroup of $p$-group contains the commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

> Let $P$ be a $p$-group and $A$ a maximal abelian normal subgroup of $P$. If $|A : C_A(x)| \le p$ for all $x \in P$, then $P' \le A$.

As far as I know I have no idea how to bring the condition about the index of $C_A(x)$ in $A$ into an argument showing that $P' \le A$, or equivalently that $P/A$ is abelian. The only "idea" what might be helpful: As $A \unlhd P$ the group $P$ acts on $A$ by conjugation, hence it acts on the cosets of $C_A(x)$ in $A$.

Any hints?

Comment: The group $A$ acts on $G$ by conjugation. $Ker=\cap C_A(x)\geq \phi(A)$. 

Since $C_G(A)=A$, $A/Ker$ act faitfully on $G/A$.And $A/Ker$ is elementary abelian.

Comment: I do not see that $A / \mbox{ker}$ is elementary abelian, and why does this implies that $P / A$ itself is abelian? For let $A$ act on $P$ by conjugation with kernel $C_A(P) = \bigcap_{x\in P} C_A(x)$. Then you say we have $a^pC_A(P) = C_A(P) \Leftrightarrow a^p \in C_A(P)$ for all $a \in A$, I do not see that? And also why does the faithful action of $A / \mbox{ker}$ on $G/A$ would imply that $G/A$ itself is abelian?

Comment: $C_A(x)$ is maximal subgroup in $A$ and $\phi(A)$ is the intersection of all maximals. Since $Ker\geq \phi (A)$, A/ker is elemantary abelian. I wrote it as an observation.

Comment: Ah okay you meant the Frattini subgroup and this is one of the properties of this subgroup. Does the action of $A / Ker$ as an elementary abelian group implies that $G/A$ is abelian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems quite challenging! For $x,y \in P$, it is enough to prove that $[x,y]$ centralizes $A$, or equivalently that the automorphisms of $A$ induced by conjugation by $xy$ and $yx$ are the same, because then the fact that $A$ is maximal abelian implies $C_G(A)=A$, so $[x,y] \in A$.

This is easy if $C_A(x)=C_A(y)$, or if either $x$ or $y$ centralizes $A$. So assume not and let $N = C_A(x) \cap C_A(y)$. Then $A/N$ is elementary abelian of order $p^2$. Let $C_A(x) = \langle a,N \rangle$ and $C_A(y) = \langle b,N \rangle$. If both $x$ and $y$ centralize $A/N$, then again it is easy, so assume not.

Since $x$ and $y$ generate a $p$-group, and their centralizers project onto different subgroups of $A/N$, they cannot both induce nontrivial actions on $A/N$.

So let's assume that $x$ acts nontrivially and $y$ acts trivially on $A/N$. Then we may assume that $a$ is chosen such that $b^x = ab$. Now $y$ does not centralize $a$, so $a^y=ac$ for some $1 \ne c \in N$. But now we find that $xy$ does not centralize any element of $A \setminus N$, contradicting the assumption that $|A:C_A(xy)| \le p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But may I ask some questions, you say if $C_A(x) = C_A(y) =: C$ then $[x,y] \in C_G(A)$ is easy, in that case I see only that the map $a \mapsto a^{[x,y]}$ is the identity on $C$, but I do not see why this implies it must be the identity on the whole of $A$ (which is equivalent to $[x,y] \in C_G(A)$)? Also your last step, that each element $A \setminus N$ is not centralized is not clear to me? Why $[d, xy] \ne 1$ if $d \in A \setminus N$?

Comment: You asked for some hints! It is straightforward to check that $a^{xy} = a^{yx}$ for all $a \in A$. In the last step, the centralizer of $xy$ in its induced action on $A/N$ is $\langle a \rangle N$, so $C_A(xy) \le \langle a,N \rangle$, but $xy$ does not centralize $a$.

Comment: Mhh, maybe I have overlooked something... if $C_A(x) = C_A(y)$ and $a \notin C_A(x)$, then $a^x \ne a, a^y \ne a$, and $a^x \cdot a^y = a^y \cdot a^x$, is this enough to prove that $a^{xy} = a^{yx}$?

Comment: No, $a^x.a^y$ is not the same as $a^{xy}$. Look, we have $a^x = at$ for some $t \in C_A(x)$ and $a^y = au$ for some $u \in C_A(y)$ so if $C_A(x)=C_A(y)$ then $a^{xy}=a^{yx}=atu$.

Comment: But this supposes $a^x C_A(x) = aC_A(x)$ and $a^y C_A(y) = aC_A(y)$ [as this is equivalent to $a^x \in aC_A(x)$ and $a^y \in aC_A(y)$], i.e. that $x$ and $y$ fix $aC_A(x)$ in their action on the cosets, as $a$ is arbitrary and about $x$ and $y$ we know nothing more than $C_A(x) = C_A(y)$ I do not see that either, does this holds or am I just confusing something?

Comment: Yes that holds! Please think a bit more about it. Remeber $P$ is a $p$-group. You asked for hints, not a detailed solution.

Comment: Okay, as $P$ is a $p$-group the number of fixed points is congruent modulo $p$. As $C_A(x)$ is fixed by $P$, and the action is on $p$ cosets, it must fix every cosets, i.e. the action is trivial. Right? [kinda strong conclusion that the action is trivial].